# Torch, how to execute a script with "dofile" and input parameters?

Tags: shell, lua, torch

I'm executing a Torch script from my Linux shell, with the `th` command. This Torch script takes two input parameters:

`th torch_script.lua input_parameter1 input_parameter2`

Now I'd like to run this script through the Torch shell. To do this, I have to use the `dofile` command. But in this case, I don't know how to pass the input parameters `input_parameter1` and `input_parameter2`.

In Torch, how to pass some input parameters to the `dofile` execution command?

---

**EDIT**: Here's the code that I'm trying to run. I'm not able to run it properly, maybe you can tell me why

external_command.lua content:

```
local arg = arg or {...} 
input_parameter = arg[1]
print("input_parameter ".. input_parameter);
```

On the shell:

```
$th
th> tempFunc = load "external_command.lua"
th> tempFunc("try")
[string "_RESULT={tempFunc("try")}"]:1: attempt to call global 'tempFunc' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    [string "_RESULT={tempFunc("try")}"]:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /home/davide/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:630: in function 'repl'
    ...vide/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:185: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x004064d0
```

---

**EDIT 2**: I tried the solution posted by TonyHsu, but it does not work anyway.
Here's what I'm doing.

I define a function `runfile()` in a script called `runfile.lua` which contains the following code:

```
function runfile(scriptName, input)
  opt = nil
  arg = input
  dofile(scriptName)
end
```

Then I use the `external_command.lua` script that I previously defined as `scriptName` input parameter for this function:

```
th> scriptName = "external_command.lua"
th> require './runfile.lua'
th> runfile(scriptName, "Hello world");
```

Unfortunately, also in this case I get an error:

```
external_command.lua:4: attempt to concatenate global 'input_parameter' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    external_command.lua:4: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    /home/davide/torch/temp/runfile.lua:4: in function 'runfile'
    [string "runfile(scriptName, "Hello world");"]:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /home/davide/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:648: in function 'repl'
    ...vide/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:185: in main chunk
[C]: at 0x004064d0
```

Comment: Use `loadfile` instead of `load`

Comment: Thanks @EgorSkriptunoff but it does not work the same. Same error...

Comment: Hey is there anybody able to help?

Comment: May be `runfile(scriptName, {"Hello world"});` ?

Comment: Hey @EgorSkriptunoff you're right! If you want to rewrite it as an answer, I'll accept it as the official answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the trick is to pass the parameters in global variable 'args'. Say, I have the following content in `external_command.lua`.

```
-- args has been set by the caller
if not args or #args == 0 then
    print('no input_parameter')
else
    print('#args = ' .. #args, 'input_parameter: ' .. args[1])
end
```

Then define runfile() as follows.

```
function runfile(f, ...)
    local tmp = args  -- save the original global args
    args = table.pack(...)
    dofile(f)
    args = tmp  -- restore args
end
```

I've tested it in th. It looks like this.

```
th> runfile('ext_command.lua', 10)
#args = 1       input_parameter: 10
                                                                      [0.0002s]
th> runfile('ext_command.lua', 'a', 'b', 'c')
#args = 3       input_parameter: a
                                                                      [0.0002s]
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `loadfile`:

```
local TempFunc = loadfile "torch_script.lua"
TempFunc(input_parameter1, input_parameter2)
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work to me. The `input_parameter1` is passed through a `chromSel = arg[1]` command, but this assignment does not work: `Error: attempt to concatenate global 'chromSel' (a nil value)`. Why?

Comment: Add `local arg = arg or {...}` at the beginning of `torch_script.lua`

Comment: Thanks. I added that line to the #1 line of the file, but it does not work. It generates the same error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to define a function first :

```
function runfile(<scriptName>, ...)
opt = nil
arg = {...}
dofile(<scriptName>)
end
```

then  run

```
runfile(<scriptName>,...)
```

Comment: Thanks TonyHsu but it does not work anyway. I edited my question to report the details of my test; can you take a look to it?